# Simple Search throws up error django

Tags: python, django

I am trying out my first Django app. Previously I built the following app using Flask and it worked.

I want my app to search github and return top 5 search items.

My app is called assign1. The assign1/views.py is as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from .application import getresult

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def search(request):
    search_term = request.GET['search_term']
    t = loader.get_template('result.html')
    c = Context({'items':getresult(search_term),'search_term':search_term,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

The assign1/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^result/$', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

My assign1/templates/index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    {% block content %}
    <div class = "container">
    <h1>Search Github</h1>
            <form action='/assign1/result'>
                <input type='text' name='search_term'><br>

                <br><br>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
            </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

My result.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Github Navigator</title></head>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h1>{{search_term}}</h1>
    {% for rep in items %}
        <h2>{{loop.index}} {{rep["respository_name"]}}</h2>
        <h3> Created {{rep["created_at"]}}</h3>
        <a href="{{rep["owner_url"]}}"><img src="{{rep["avatar_url"]}}" alt="avatar" height="42" width="42"/></a>
        {{rep["owner_login"]}}
        <h3>LastCommit</h3>
        {{rep["sha"]}} {{rep["commit_message"]}}  {{rep["commit_author_name"]}}
        <hr/>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

The index opens fine. When I click the button, the website url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/result?search_term=arrow`
I get an error saying Page not found

```
Using the URLconf defined in assignment.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^assign1/
^admin/
The current URL, result, didn't match any of these
```

My main urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   # Examples:
   # url(r'^$', 'myproject.views.home', name = 'home'),
   # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
   url(r'^assign1/', include('assign1.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?search_term=arrow`, or change the URL pattern to `'^result$', views.search, name='search')`.

Comment: What does your main urls.py look like?

Comment: @ColinBasnett I get the same error trying both

Comment: Hmm, your error doesn't match your code; the error says you're going to /result, but your template says it's posting to /assgn1/result. Of course, it should be /ass**i**gn1/result.

Comment: @wpercy There is a typo in `action='/assgn1/result'` in form. It should be `action='/assign1/result'`.

Comment: @gitblame I fixed the typo. But I still get the error

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please check now